# Whether the anycast nodes can not in the same AS, and whether the different AS can pronounce the same IP segment?

Tags: bgp, anycast

The Anycast realize is through annunciate the same IP address in the different node using BGP protocol.

you see the Server A and Server B use the BGP annunciate the same IP address `10.0.0.1`.

[image]

There I have some questions,

1. Annunciate IP to eBGP is through the router, so there should have a router which is ignore there(before Server A and Server B), right?
2. The Server A and Server B must not in the same AS, right? the can not in a same AS, right ? so the diffirent AS eBGP router can pronounce the same IP address range, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're asking with your first question, maybe you can clarify that a bit more.

But to answer your second question: the servers do not have to be in the same ASN, but they absolutely can be. Both anycast from one single ASN and from multiple ASNs can work. A single ASN is often used (for example by CDNs like [CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflares-architecture-eliminating-single-p/)) to provide fastest path to their networks throughout the world, but there are also examples where multiple ASNs are used, for example the [6to4 gateway service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4) which used to be hosted by many network providers.